# Qual è il senso di "nicchiare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> Lo specchio pigro del mare cominciò a fremere, svelandosi della caligine; le case della cittadina aggrappolata sul porto **nicchiavano** ancora, mezze addormentate nel crepuscolo, quando improvvisamente furono scosse da un caldo fiume di luce che si rovesciò su di loro: il sole s'era levato di schianto.

Ho cercato il verbo "nicchiare" in alcuni dizionari, tuttavia non riesco a vedere a quale accezione corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il verbo *nicchiare* ha tra i suoi primi significati quello figurato di «mostrarsi incerto, esitante, indugiare […] a prendere una decisione o ad aderire alle proposte di qualcuno» (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nicchiare1). Nel brano indica “l’incertezza” mattutina delle case, ancora non completamente sveglie, fino al sorgere completo e dirompente del sole.

Answer (score 1):

Il significato di [nicchiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nicchiare2/) che si adatta al contesto da te citato è il seguente:

> **nicchiare²** v. tr. [der. *di nicchia*] (*io nìcchio, ecc.*), ant. o letter. – Collocare, sistemare in una nicchia o in altro vano ricavato
> in una superficie, e per estens. inserire, collocare in genere, anche
> in senso fig.: *fece ... tagliuzzar pitture de’ più gran maestri per
> nicchiarle ne’ riquadri delle sue stanze* (Algarotti). Nel rifl.,
> ***sistemarsi, rannicchiarsi, ritirarsi in un posto come in una nicchia, e in senso fig. trovare una qualche sistemazione***:
> *nicchiarsi fra le lenzuola; siam ... di Pistoia venuti qui a
> dirittura: e qui stiam cercando dove nicchiarci* (Alfieri); *una delle
> due ninfe approfittò della tregua per nicchiarsi nel vano d’una
> finestra* (I. Nievo).

Praticamente le case della cittadina stavano ancora rannicchiate, mezze addormentate nel crepuscolo, in attesa che il sole le risvegliasse con il suo improvviso calore.

Comment: Mi sembra che in questo caso il significato più adatto sia quello figurato: «mostrarsi incerto, esitante» (indicato nella voce Treccani).

Comment: @abarisone: Tuttavia, secondo il dizionario, questo verbo con questo significato si usa in modo riflessivo e quindi dovrebbe essere "le case della cittadina aggrappolata sul porto ***si nicchiavano*** ancora".